# Racket - recursive contracts

Tags: racket

I was trying to make a recursive contract for my binary tree struct:

```
(struct node (l r)) 
(struct leaf (val))

(define (tree-of val)
    (or/c (struct/c leaf val) (struct/c node (tree-of val) (tree-of val))))

(define/contract (id-tree t)
    (-> (tree-of symbol?) (tree-of symbol?))
    t)

(id-tree (leaf 'a))
```

It seems though that my contract leads to an infinite loop, not sure why. First of all, shouldn't it stop after or/c receives any positive value (from (struct/c leaf val) in this case)?
Even if it checks the second predicate, (leaf 'a) is obviously not a node, so why would it recursively call tree-of again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some sense, there are two phases: contract computing and contract checking. Your example doesn't terminate in the contract computing phase.

Suppose you attach `(or/c <a> <b>)` to a value `x`. `or/c` is simply a normal function, so under call-by-value (which is what Racket has), *both* `<a>` and `<b>` will be computed.

If nothing goes wrong, `<a>` and `<b>` should evaluate to contract values `va` and `vb` respectively. The contract checking then starts by testing `x` against `va`. If it fails, then it tests `x` against `vb`.

The problem with your example is that the process of computing contract values doesn't even terminate. No checking has even occurred yet by that point.

To accomplish what you want to do, use `flat-rec-contract`:

```
(define (tree-of/c val)
  (flat-rec-contract tree-of
                     (struct/c leaf val)
                     (struct/c node tree-of tree-of)))
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation, now it makes sense! :P